# WordPress Signing Key Required

Tags: wordpress

WordPress v6.1.1 CiviCRM v5.59.3

So, this is the new thing added for the current CiviCRM. In all honesty, I have no idea what is going on with it or why I need it. I followed the link from inside our CiviCRM to the page that created the Key and added it accordingly, as seen from the image below with respect to adding it after the site key.

[image: Image showing Signing Key from https://civisettings.symbiotic.coop/ added]

Comment: What's the question/problem?

Comment: Exactly what I wrote. CiviCRM says I need a WordPress Signing Key. I created the key and entered it precisely as requested and get the error of The system requires a cryptographic signing key. Please configure CIVICRM_SIGN_KEYS. Located here: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/secret-keys/ and obtained the key here: https://civisettings.symbiotic.coop/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why, but apparently the original data never saved. It now works.

Thanks!